# data.table and stratified means

Tags: r, data.table

I've got some code that generate stratified weighted means and 
I'm certain this worked a few months ago.  But, but I'm not sure what the current problem is. 
(I apologize - this must be very basic stuff):

```
dp=
structure(list(seqn = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 3L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 
5L, 13L, 2L, 14L, 3L, 9L, 6L, 7L), sex = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), bmi = c(22.8935608711259, 
27.0944623781918, 40.4637162938634, 23.7649712675423, 15.3193372705538, 
31.1280302540991, 21.4866354393239, 20.3200254374398, 32.331092513536, 
25.3679771839413, 33.9400508162971, 14.7048592172926, 25.5243757788688, 
23.4331882363495, 27.6428134168995, 29.3923629426172, 24.9547209666314, 
17.0522203606383, 15.51, 22, 30.62, 30.94, 29.1, 25.57, 24.9, 
27.33, 17.63, 18.48, 22.56, 29.39), tc = c(273L, 181L, 150L, 
201L, 142L, 165L, 235L, 219L, 298L, 222L, 143L, 134L, 268L, 160L, 
236L, 225L, 260L, 140L, 162L, 132L, 156L, 140L, 279L, 314L, 215L, 
174L, 129L, 148L, 153L, 245L), swt = c(1645, 3318, 2280, 1574, 
4062, 1627, 14604, 24675, 975, 975, 2697, 1559, 1737.58, 1730.23, 
19521.36, 28080.57, 1248.43, 13745.77, 5251.76464426326, 6497.194885522, 
15915.7023420765, 3740.96809540218, 16574.177622509, 307.32513798849, 
4720.89748295751, 3247.78896499604, 7698.70949077031, 1262.6450411464, 
6609.43340735515, 4254.23723479882)), .Names = c("seqn", "sex", 
"bmi", "tc", "swt"), row.names = c(20560L, 20561L, 20562L, 20563L, 
20565L, 20566L, 20567L, 20568L, 20569L, 20570L, 20571L, 20572L, 
61335L, 61336L, 61338L, 61339L, 61340L, 61341L, 95465L, 96890L, 
104613L, 105988L, 107581L, 112267L, 113403L, 114292L, 119979L, 
120271L, 125939L, 135699L), class = "data.frame")

dt=data.table(dp, key='sex')

sapply(df,function(x)weighted.mean(x,df$swt))  #this works to weighted mean
dt[,lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm=T), .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')]  
     #this also works for overall unweighted mean

dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x)weighted.mean(x,swt, na.rm=TRUE)), by=key(dt), .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')]
```

but this gives the error: 
`Error in weighted.mean.default(x, swt, na.rm = TRUE) :  object 'swt' not found`

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.8.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: @DWin, I think the first line of code (after the dput) creates a `data.table`, but I don't see where `df` is defined (which is used in the `sapply` call)

Comment: You are right. Changing df to dp allows success. I'll delete my first comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### UPDATE (from Arun): This is now fixed in [v1.8.11](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=240). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1009):

> o  `DT[, lapply(.SD, function(), by=]` did not see columns of DT when optimisation is "on". This is now fixed, [#2381](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2381&group_id=240&atid=975). Tests added and tested successfully. Thanks to David F for reporting on SO:
>        [data.table and stratified means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13441868/data-table-and-stratified-means)

---

This is indeed a bug introduced somewhere between 1.8.2 and 1.8.6.

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x) weighted.mean(x,swt, na.rm=TRUE)), by=key(dt),
    .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')] 
Error in weighted.mean.default(x, swt, na.rm = TRUE) : 
    object 'swt' not found
```

To work around this in the meantime, either turn off optimization :

```
options(datatable.optimize=FALSE)
dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x)weighted.mean(x,swt, na.rm=TRUE)), by=key(dt),    
    .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')]
   sex      bmi       tc      swt
1:   1 25.64376 206.0115 17171.20
2:   2 23.73566 193.8727 11467.47
```

or, don't wrap with `function()` :

```
options(datatable.optimize=TRUE)
dt[,lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, swt, na.rm=TRUE), by=key(dt),    
    .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')] 
   sex      bmi       tc      swt
1:   1 25.64376 206.0115 17171.20
2:   2 23.73566 193.8727 11467.47
```

We are making more use of optimization now, but this case slipped through the test suite: tests 825.1, 825.2 and 825.3 didn't cover an argument to a function being another column, within an anonymous `function()`. It would be a problem where the function isn't already given; i.e., unlike this case, where the `function()` can just be omitted since `weighted.mean` is already given and can be applied as-is.

You can see how optimization modifies j by setting `verbose=TRUE` (either per query or with the global option). In this case nothing would have been revealed as wrong by that verbose output, but just mentioning it as an aside.

Now filed as [#2381: Optimization of lapply(.SD, function() ...) no longer sees columns inside ...](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2381&group_id=240&atid=975). Will fix and add tests so this can't regress again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to keep it simple:

```
dt[,list(bmi_m=weighted.mean(bmi,swt,na.rm=TRUE),
         tc_m=weighted.mean(tc,swt,na.rm=TRUE),
         swt_m=weighted.mean(swt,swt,na.rm=TRUE)),by=key(dt)]
```

I think this is also reasonably fast.

Comment: It wasn't the data.table step that was throwing an error, but rather the sapply step using the wrong argument.

Comment: @DWin I am referring to the last part (calculating the stratified weighted means): `dt[,lapply(.SD, function(x)weighted.mean(x,swt, na.rm=TRUE)), by=key(dt), .SDcols=c('bmi','tc','swt')]`, which appears to be overly complicated and probably also not the most efficient.

Comment: If it works, which it does on my machine anyway, it doesn't appear to me to likely be any shower. Testing with a benchmark on such a small data dataset would probably be uninformative.

Comment: @DWin It does not work on my machine. And in my experience doing things with `.SD` is slower.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think the problem is with a change in the data.table.  My code (with the .SD) works fine in ubuntu with data.table 1.8.2, but not in windows with data.table 1.8.6.  I'll try to get in touch with Mathew

Comment: Everyone is right here (DWin, Roland and David). Roland, you're right about not using `.SD` in general. What's new is that optimization now takes `j=lapply(.SD,...` and changes it to what you've presented, basically, before evaluation. Optimization makes it more complicated, and timing more difficult to predict, but hopefully with `verbose=TRUE` and being able to switch on/off optimization, there should be enough to work it out. In future we might have more levels, like gcc -O1, -O2 and -O3 does. Most of the time most users don't need to know (hopefully) ...